# How to fix 'Cannot assign requested address?'

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, ip, bind

Both the IP address and Port are confirmed not used by `netstat -a -n.` When I use gdb and break in the method calling bind I see that the correct IP address and Port are being used along with a reasonable socket address length of 16. This is for a UDP Listener. The remote IP is static and read from a configuration file.

This is the code,

```
void CSocket::Bind(IpEndPoint& endPoint)
{
    int bindResult = bind( socketHandle, endPoint.GetSockAddrPtr(), 
        endPoint.GetAddrLength());
    if(bindResult < 0)
    {
        TRACE_ERROR("Failed to bind to socket. %s. IpAddress %s Port %d AddrLength %d",
            strerror(errno), endPoint.GetIpAddressString(), 
            ntohs(endPoint.GetPort()), endPoint.GetAddrLength());
```

this is from gdb,

> Breakpoint 1, CSocket::Bind (this=0x819fa24, ipAddress="192.0.2.77",
>   port=4185) at Socket.cpp:126

and this is the TRACE_ERROR from the code above

> ERROR: Failed to bind to socket. errno 99 (Cannot assign requested address).
>   IpAddress 192.0.2.77 Port 4185 AddrLength 16

I've been re-reading [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) but not finding a clue. This is UDP so a connection should not be required to bind. The firewall is off. Where else should I be looking?

Comment: I'd look at how the ip address as string is converted to the required `struct sockaddr` object. Is the address you want to bind to really a local one? If it shall be the remote host, use connect instead. Is the port already in use? (...)

Comment: Just a tip: I personally prefer the error code rather than the error string - and I'm probably not the only one... Might be a good idea to use e. g. `"%d (%s)", errno, strerror(errno)` to satisfy both fractions.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks. Added error code as you suggested. Why does UDP need `connect` if it is `connectionless?`

Comment: Following on what @Aconcagua said: You want to bind an address that *is* local (not one that's "not in use"). You can't just make up a local address. You either use `INADDR_ANY` to bind to any address, or you need to bind one that is assigned to one of your local interfaces. This is likely the problem. (`bind` sets the local address, `connect` sets the remote address -- or, with UDP, you can specify the remote address per packet with `sendto`.)

Comment: @jacknad With UDP, you don't need to call connect. You can, this will be the default address to send data to (i. e. you then can use send instead of sendto). But you are always able to send data to any other client with sendto and another address specified. Be aware, though, that if you connect your udp socket to a specific address, this will be the only one you receive data from (see [connect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html)).

Comment: This is for a UDP Listener and the remote IP is static. I'll add this clarification to the body of the question.

Comment: Is **192.0.2.77** an IP address which is currently assigned to your host? If not, you will need to change it to either INADDR_ANY (**0.0.0.0**, which will listen on all IP addresses on the host), or an IP address which is actually assigned to the computer on which you are running this program.

Comment: @JoelC 192.0.2.77 is a static IP address assigned to the host

Comment: @GilHamilton Adding the interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` and another Network Adapter in settings seemed to allow the Listener to bind without complaint. I suppose I need to learn a little more about how local interfaces work. If you move your comment to the answer section I'll accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on what @Aconcagua said: You want to bind an address that is local (not one that's "not in use"). You can't just make up a local address. You either use `INADDR_ANY` to bind to any address, or you need to bind one that is assigned to one of your local interfaces. This is likely the problem. (`bind` sets the local address, `connect` sets the remote address -- or, with UDP, you can specify the remote address per packet with `sendto`.) – Gil Hamilton